# What happens if the item that created a magical effect ceases to exist?

Tags: spells, magic-items, anima-beyond-fantasy, duration

Let us assume that I have an item bearing two charges of Imitate (Creation 30) as an Automatic Spell (Prometheum Exxet).

Using one charge of Imitate, I duplicate the object.

Using the charge of Imitate on the object I have duplicated, I duplicate the original object.

I continue duplicating the original object with its duplicates for an hour.

What happens when the timer runs out on the first duplicated object?

Answer (score 1):

So, there are several things at work here. The short answer is that after one hour the first object vanishes as if it never existed. Automatic spells that cast what would normally be a daily upkeep last an hour. That aside. There is a certain order to how things happen here.

They go as follows:

- The Spell triggered (somehow).
- Charges decrement.
- The item that you target is seen, and everything about it at that moment in time is noted down. (The Presence is critical here)
- After this, it finally would have the copy made.

Additionally, as Imitate would be a level 2 power for an artifact, the item in question needs a minimum of 15 presence to even hold a level 2 power. It then increases its presence by that same number, to total of 30 presence. This remains within the capabilities of the Imitate spell.

With all this known, because the object is actively maintaining the spell it would behave identically to the case of a wizard suddenly vanishing.

Comment: Do you have a source for "the pbject is actively maintaining the spell"?  Do you have a source for what happens when a wizard vanishes and stops paying upkeep?  There are spells that add directly to the pool of Zeon a spell has for maintenance...

Comment: In short, this is well-thought-out and all, but it stops a few words short of actually answering the question.

Comment: Also, you used the numbers for a level 3 power.  Gonna submit an edit for that.